# How to validate router supplied match property in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, eslint

I am using Visual studio code with eslint validation but it seems I can't get through validation error with the use of `react-router-dom` and a supplied property `{match}`. How should I validate the property that is encapsulated in curly braces?

This is my attempt using just simple `PropTypes`. I have also tried `react-router-prop-types` but the result is the same. My eslint extension is saying an error that `'match' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)`. Validation of normal properties works perfectly.

```
function MyFunction({match}) {
    return <div>
        <h1>Something</h1>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(match)}</p>
    </div>;
}

MyFunction.PropTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try component property `propTypes` with a lowercase "p". I'd also add `isRequired` to ensure it's required.

```
function MyFunction({match}) {
    return <div>
        <h1>Something</h1>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(match)}</p>
    </div>;
}

MyFunction.propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Hopefully that helps!